# Why does my supervisor fail on start_child with undef?

Tags: module, erlang, erlang-supervisor

I am trying to run a `simple_one_for_one supervisor` where the `supervisor` and `worker` are placed in separate modules and i keep getting the below error when using `supervisor:start_child`:

```
>A=sup:start_link().
>B=supervisor:start_child(A,[]).
{error,{'EXIT',{undef,[{worker,start_link,[],[]},
                       {supervisor,do_start_child_i,3,
                                   [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,379}]},
                       {supervisor,handle_call,3,
                                   [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,404}]},
                       {gen_server,try_handle_call,4,
                                   [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,661}]},
                       {gen_server,handle_msg,6,
                                   [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,690}]},
                       {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                 [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}}}
```

**Supervisor**

```
-module(sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).
-compile([export_all]).

start_link()->
    {ok,Pid}=supervisor:start_link(?MODULE,[]),
    io:format("sugi pl"),
    Pid.



init(_Args) ->
     RestartStrategy = {simple_one_for_one, 10, 60},
     ChildSpec = {
                  worker, 
                  {worker, start_link, []},  //tried adding here a parameter in the A
                  permanent,
                  brutal_kill, 
                  worker,
                  [sup]
                },
    {ok, {RestartStrategy,[ChildSpec]}}.
```

**Worker**

```
-module(worker).
-compile(export_all).


start_link([Arg])->  //tried both [Arg] and Arg
    {ok,Pid}=spawn_link(?MODULE,init,[]),
    Pid.


init([Time])->
    receive->
        {From,Msg}->From !{Time,Msg},
                     init(Time)
    end.
```

**Command**

```
>c("[somepath]/sup.erl"),A=sup:start_link(),B=supervisor:start_child(A,[]).
```

I can see clearly that the problem is when trying to add a child.Somehow the `init` function is not called properly but i do not see why.(Badmatch)
I have tried adding a parameter in the `A` of the `MFA`  of the `ChildSpec` to no avail

Comment: are you sure that `worker` is compiled and loaded?

Comment: I am running in the erlang shell the command that i wrote above.Does `worker` module need to be compiled if it is used by the `sup` module ? Wont they both be compiled ?

Comment: `undef,[{worker,start_link,[]` says that worker:start_link/0 does not exist, but worker defines only start_link/1. It could be that your modules are not in sync. Ensure that both sup and worker are using the same arity for worker:start_link and recompile both modules before retrying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code.

- The return value of `sup:start_link/0` is wrong; you're returning Pid instead of `{ok, Pid}`.
- While it's not really incorrect, you're using `supervisor:start_link/2`, which doesn't register the supervisor name. Having the name is handy, so it's better to use `supervisor:start_link/3`:

  ```
  supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []),
  ```

  This associates the module name with its process id, allowing you to use the process name in your shell commands rather than using pid variables.
- You have an `io:format/2` call in `sup:start_link/0`, presumably for debugging. A much better way of debugging is to call `sys:trace(sup, true)` from your shell once you've started the `sup` supervisor. You can turn it off from the shell as well, by specifying `false` instead of `true` as the second argument.

Fixing the above issues leaves use with the following definition of `sup:start_link/0`:

```
start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).
```

Let's recompile, start the supervisor, then compile `worker` (after fixing its syntax errors), and then trace the supervisor as we try to start a child:

```
1> c(sup).
sup.erl:3: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,sup}
2> sup:start_link().
{ok,<0.94.0>}
3> sys:trace(sup, true).
ok
4> c(worker).
worker.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
worker.erl:5: Warning: variable 'Arg' is unused
{ok,worker}
5> supervisor:start_child(sup, []).
*DBG* sup got call {start_child,[]} from <0.81.0>
*DBG* sup sent {error,
                   {'EXIT',
                       {undef,
                           [{worker,start_link,[],[]},
                            {supervisor,do_start_child_i,3,
                                [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,379}]},
...
```

This abbreviated trace output shows that `sup` died when it tried to start a `worker` by calling `worker:start_link/0` (the `[]` indicates there are zero arguments). The child specification tells `sup` to start it this way, since it contains

```
{worker, start_link, []}
```

and we started the child via `supervisor:start_child(sup, [])`. For a `simple_one_for_one` child, the arguments sent to its start function are composed of the argument list from the child specification combined with the arguments specified in the call to `supervisor:start_child/2`; in this case, that's the equivalent of `[] ++ []` which is the same as `[]`, indicating no arguments. Let's change the `worker:start_link/1` function to `worker:start_link/0` instead, recompile it, and try again:

```
6> c(worker).
worker.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,worker}
7> supervisor:start_child(sup, []).
*DBG* sup got call {start_child,[]} from <0.81.0>
*DBG* sup sent {error,
                   {'EXIT',
                       {{badmatch,<0.94.0>},
                        [{worker,start_link,0,[{file,"worker.erl"},{line,6}]},
...
```

This time, the abbreviated output shows a `badmatch`. This is because `spawn_link/3` returns a pid, but `worker:start_link/0` is expecting it to return `{ok, Pid}`. Let's fix that, and also fix the return value to be `{ok, Pid}` instead of just `Pid`:

```
start_link()->
    Pid = spawn_link(?MODULE,init,[]),
    {ok, Pid}.
```

Then let's recompile and try again:

```
8> c(worker).
worker.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,worker}
9> supervisor:start_child(sup, []).
*DBG* sup got call {start_child,[]} from <0.81.0>
*DBG* sup sent {ok,<0.106.0>} to <0.81.0>, new state {state,
                                                      {local,sup},
                                                      simple_one_for_one,
                                                      {[worker],
                                                       #{worker =>
                                                          {child,undefined,
                                                           worker,
                                                           {worker,
                                                            start_link,[]},
                                                           permanent,
                                                           brutal_kill,worker,
                                                           [sup]}}},
                                                      {maps,
                                                       #{<0.106.0> => []}},
                                                      10,60,[],0,sup,[]}
*DBG* sup got {'EXIT',<0.106.0>,{undef,[{worker,init,[],[]}]}}
```

OK, this time the supervisor actually started the child, but it died immediately because it's trying to call `worker:init/0` but only `worker:init/1` is defined. Because the child dies immediately, the supervisor tries repeatedly to start it, based on its restart strategy:

```
RestartStrategy = {simple_one_for_one, 10, 60},
```

Because this is a hard error, it fails instantly every time, and the supervisor dies after 10 failed restarts in 60 seconds or less, just like it's supposed to:

```
=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 20-Apr-2020::10:43:43.557307 ===
    supervisor: {local,sup}
    errorContext: shutdown
    reason: reached_max_restart_intensity
    offender: [{pid,<0.117.0>},
               {id,worker},
               {mfargs,{worker,start_link,[]}},
               {restart_type,permanent},
               {shutdown,brutal_kill},
               {child_type,worker}]
** exception error: shutdown
```

It appears from your code that you're attempting to pass some sort of `Time` argument to `worker:init/1`, so let's change `start_link/0` to pass a timestamp:

```
start_link()->
    Pid = spawn_link(?MODULE,init,[os:timestamp()]),
    {ok, Pid}.
```

Let's also fix `init/1` to take the argument directly, rather than in a list:

```
init(Time) ->
    receive
        {From,Msg} ->
            From ! {Time,Msg},
            init(Time)
end.
```

Let's restart the supervisor, recompile `worker`, and try again:

```
10> sup:start_link().
{ok,<0.119.0>}
11> sys:trace(sup, true).
ok
12> c(worker).
worker.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,worker}
13> {ok, Child} = supervisor:start_child(sup, []).
*DBG* sup got call {start_child,[]} from <0.118.0>
*DBG* sup sent {ok,<0.127.0>} to <0.118.0>, new state {state,
                                                       {local,sup},
                                                       simple_one_for_one,
                                                       {[worker],
                                                        #{worker =>
                                                           {child,undefined,
                                                            worker,
                                                            {worker,
                                                             start_link,[]},
                                                            permanent,
                                                            brutal_kill,
                                                            worker,
                                                            [sup]}}},
                                                       {maps,
                                                        #{<0.127.0> => []}},
                                                       10,60,[],0,sup,[]}
{ok,<0.127.0>}
```

It looks like it worked. Let's see if the supervisor agrees, by asking it how many children it has:

```
14> supervisor:count_children(sup).
...
[{specs,1},{active,1},{supervisors,0},{workers,1}]
```

It has one worker, just as we expected. Finally, let's send a message to the worker and see if it responds as expected:

```
15> Child ! {self(), "are you there?"}.
{<0.118.0>,"are you there?"}
16> flush().
Shell got {{1587,394860,258120},"are you there?"}
ok
```

Now it all seems to work.

One final fix is to change the modules in your child specification; rather than `[sup]` it should be the module itself, `[worker]`. With that change, your revised working modules are below. You might also want to reconsider whether you want to use `permanent` for the children, since this is a `simple_one_for_one` supervisor; `transient` is likely a better choice, but I've left it as originally written. Consider reviewing the [Supervisor Behavior documentation](https://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html) for more information.

**Supervisor**

```
-module(sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).
-compile([export_all]).

start_link()->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

init(_Args) ->
     RestartStrategy = {simple_one_for_one, 10, 60},
     ChildSpec = {
                  worker,
                  {worker, start_link, []},
                  permanent,
                  brutal_kill,
                  worker,
                  [worker]
                },
    {ok, {RestartStrategy,[ChildSpec]}}.
```

**Worker**

```
-module(worker).
-compile(export_all).

start_link()->
    Pid = spawn_link(?MODULE,init,[os:timestamp()]),
    {ok, Pid}.

init(Time) ->
    receive
        {From,Msg} ->
            From ! {Time,Msg},
            init(Time)
    end.
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent answer already posted, I would like add a few points to explain the behavior observed in the question.

The start value in childspec is a tuple `{Mod, Fun, ArgsList}` and child process can be spawned by calling `supervisor:start_child(Supervisor, List)`. The supervisor start's the child process by calling `erlang:apply(Mod, Fun, List++ArgsList)`.

In this case, the start value is `{worker, start_link, []}` and child was spawned by calling `supervisor:start_child(A, [])`. The supervisor attempted to call `erlang:apply(worker, start_link, [])`. This means the supervisor was expecting `worker:start_link/0` to be defined in the `worker` module. But the `worker` module defined `worker:start_link/1`. Hence the `undef` error.

Given the function definition

```
start_link([Arg]) ->
  %% do stuff
```

The best was to spawn the child process is

- let start value in child spec be `{worker, start_link, []}`
- call `supervisor:start_child(A, [[Value]])`

It maybe simpler to define the function as

```
start_link(Arg) ->
  %% so stuff
```

and call `supervisor:start_child(A, [Value])`